# Implementing memory pool

Tags: c, memory-management, embedded

I want to make a memory pool manager for a embedded system project. I want to make a separate header and corresponding implementation in a .c file (say mempool.c). My doubt here is, when I call malloc() in the function implementations in this file, which heap memory am I actually using?

Given that there are other files (say foo1.c and foo2.c) that use the header "mempool.h" and the corresponding functions in mempool.c. So, when I compile and execute foo1.c and foo2.c simultaneously, will their calls to the functions in mempool invoke allocations on 2 completely separate heaps or the same one?

Comment: Too broad, but embedded systems typically don't have the standard library available and using `malloc` & friends is a very bad idea. That's the reason one uses memory pools ...

Comment: Are foo1.c and foo2.c compiled into the same program or two separate programs?

Comment: they are individually separate programs all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *three* C source-files in play: `mempool, foo1, foo2`.

The `.h` file(s) are *header* files which describe what the functions "look like," and how they are to be called.

When you compile either `foo1` or `foo2`, the object-code from `mempool.o` will be *statically linked* into them.

Having done this, they are now "two entirely separate programs," both of which contain an identical bit of object-code.

When the two programs execute, each of them will have their own private heap.  Although both of them contain the same object-code that is used for memory-pool management, they are unrelated to one another.

If you *do* want the programs to actually "share memory," you must use a named shared-memory segment. *(`shmget`, etc ...),* and you must design your memory-pool manager code to find, open, and properly use that shared resource.  Once again, both programs will contain their own independent copy of the object-code of your memory-pool manager.

*(Hint:* "this has already been done." You can **find** complete libraries that do this, on places like GitHub, instead of embarking on a custom-made implementation, yourself.)

===
**Additional Note:**

I would also like to comment, in passing, that a **third** possibility exists: *dynamically-loaded* libraries.

When you take this approach, the object-code is loaded by the application at runtime, and it *does not* become "part of" the object-code of the applications that use it. Instead, it becomes accessible to them. Furthermore, the *operating system* is aware of the sharing, and it **may** recognize a *single* instance that is being shared. It **may** allow a common set of memory-allocations to be "owned by" *that single, shared instance.* Operating-systems (and versions, "historic vs. modern-day" *e.g.* of MS-Windows ...) vary on this particular point.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very lucid answer!